How do I include newlines with PowerShell.AddCommand("Set-Content") in c#?
I have code like the following that turns a list of strings into one string of the contents separated by \n
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("string1");
list.Add("string2");
list.Add("string3");

string stringOfListContents = string.Join("\n", list);

then when I write the string to a output file like:
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.Streams.ClearStreams();
    PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Set-Content");

    PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("Path", outputFile);
    PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("Value", stringOfListContents);

    PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
}

The result is
string1string2string3

but I would like the result in the txt file to be like
string1
string2
string3


im not able to reproduce your issue. as aside, there is no need to join the string in this case, you could just use the pipeline input: .AddCommand("Set-Content").AddParameter("Path", "test.txt").Invoke(new[]{ "foo", "bar", "baz" });

try use "`n" instead "\n"

\nis a literal character in a c# string.\n` is the new line character. OP's code has no issue that can be reproduced.

How are you viewing the contents of the text file? Does whatever you’re using treat a single \n as a line break? It’s a long shot, but the file contents might be what you want, just the way you’re viewing it might not be displaying it how you expect…

Using Environment.NewLine worked for me

Seems like you've already found the solution to your issue using Environment.NewLine to join the strings however there isn't a reason to join them for this specific case, you could pass-in the list via the .Invoke(input) overload:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management.Automation;

List<string> list = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];
string outputFile = @"a\path\text.txt";

using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance
        .AddCommand("Set-Content")
        .AddParameter("Path", outputFile)
        .Invoke(list);
}


I just used the same code of yours, but instead of the "\n" string constant, I would use the Environment.NewLine property to assure you are getting the correct new line string according to your current environment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-8.0
The code is almost the same, but just changed this line, and it worked for me:
string stringOfListContents = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);

